# Get last match with Boost::Regex

Tags: c++, regex, boost

I have a regular expression in C++ with Boost which matches lines in multi-line strings. Regex search finds the first match, however I'm interested in the last line which matches.

The code I'm using now is something like this:

```
matched = boost::regex_search(input, results, regex);               
if (!matched) {
    return -1; // error code
}
matched_string = results["Group"];
```

If `regex` was `"(?<Group>Data.)"` and `input` was `"Data1 Data2 Data3"`, then `matched_string` is now `"Data1"`. I want it to be `"Data3"`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`operator[]` of `match_results` returns a `sub_match`.
`sub_match` inherits `std::pair` of iterators.
Its `first` and `second` members correspond to matched range.
So, you can use its `second` for start point of new search.
For example:

```
string  input = "Data1 Data2 Data3";
regex  re("(?<Group>Data.)");
string::const_iterator  begin = input.begin(), end = input.end();
smatch  results;
while ( regex_search( begin, end, results, re ) ) {
  smatch::value_type  r = results["Group"];
  begin = r.second;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Using `smatch::const_reference r = results["Group"]` should avoid some unnecessary copying.